# saving weights of a tensorflow model in Databricks

Tags: tensorflow, databricks, huggingface-transformers

In a Databricks notebook which is running on Cluster1 when I do

```
path='dbfs:/Shared/P1-Prediction/Weights_folder/Weights'
model.save_weights(path)
```

and then immediately try

```
ls 'dbfs:/Shared/P1-Prediction/Weights_folder'
```

I see the actual weights file in the output display

But When I run the exact same command
`ls 'dbfs:/Shared/P1-Prediction/Weights_folder'`
on a different Databricks notebook which is running on cluster 2, I am getting the error

```
ls: cannot access 'dbfs:/Shared/P1-Prediction/Weights_folder': No such file or directory
```

I am not able to intrepret this. Does that mean my "save_weights" is saving the weights in clusters memory and not in an actual physical location? If so is there a solution for it.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow uses Python's local file API that doesn't work with `dbfs:/...` - you need to change path to use `/dbfs/...` instead of `dbfs:/...`.

But really, it could be better to log model using MLflow, in this case you can easily load it for inference.  See [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/mlflow/index.html) and maybe this [example](https://github.com/amesar/mlflow-fun/blob/master/databricks/notebooks/models_basic/python/05_TensorFlow_Autologging.py).